# XElement add style

Tags: c#, asp.net, xelement

Im trying to have a XElement with style like:

```
<g style="fill-opacity:0.7">
```

so im doing this:

```
XElement root = new XElement("g");
root.SetAttributeValue("style",
                from attributes in Child.Attributes
                where char.IsUpper(attributes.Key[0]) & !attributes.Value.ToString().StartsWith(transformNS)
                select new XAttribute("style", attributes.Key + ":" + attributes.Value));
```

But what i have is

```
<g style="System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Object],System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]">
```

someone can help me?

best regards

Comment: Are you trying to select a single child attribute?

Comment: could be more than one

Comment: So how do you want to combine them? Your code doesn't contain anything to do that.

Comment: linq will put all attributes in style

Answer (score 0):

That's because your are selecting a complete XAttribute as the value of an attribute.
You need to iterate over your properties and concenate them into a string. Then use this string as the value of your attribute.

Something like this:

```
XElement root = new XElement("g");
IEnumerable<string> styleprops = from attributes in Child.Attributes
                                 where char.IsUpper(attributes.Key[0]) & !attributes.Value.ToString().StartsWith(transformNS)
                                 select attributes.Key + ":" + attributes.Value

string value = string.empty;

foreach(string prop in styleprops){
    value += prop + ";";
}

root.SetAttributeValue("style", value);
```

Comment: OK, happy to help. (Please mark the reply as an answer if it solves your problem)